# Relationship between three entities in Doctrine

Tags: php, database, doctrine

I have Doctrine setup with all my tables in my database, and working properly.

I have those three entities: Users, Groups and News

There is a many-to-many relationship between Users and Groups. (I put my users in groups)

There is also a many-to-many relationship between News and Groups. (I give access to a News item to a few Groups)

Database Schema:

[image: My database schema for the relevant part]

I want to get the News that a given User has access to.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Doctrine?

EDIT: I should add that I already had the solution nailed down with a straight SQL query before I started to use Doctrine, I want to know the Doctrine way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This thread explain the issues about many to many relationships in doctrine.

[many-to-many relationship in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868560/many-to-many-relationship-in-doctrine)

This blog post explain how to handle such events.

http://melikedev.com/2009/12/09/symfony-w-doctrine-saving-many-to-many-mm-relationships/